# github action pulumi preview command output

Tags: github-actions, cicd, pulumi

My github action workflow is as follows:

```
- name: Preview changes to Infra  
  uses: pulumi/actions@v4
  id: pulumi
  with:
    command: preview
    stack-name: ${{ env.PULUMY_XXXX }}
    work-dir: ${{ env.PULUMY_XXXXX }}
    color: always
  env:
    PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.PULUMI_XXXXXX }}
```

and the output from this step is very verbose and seen below:
[image]

The only part I would like displayed is what is in the red box. Anyone have any suggestions how to reduce the output ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a configuration for that. You might want to create an issue on https://github.com/pulumi/actions repo to request its inclusion.

Answer (score -1):

```
- name: Preview changes to Infra  
  uses: pulumi/actions@v4
  id: pulumi
  with:
    command: preview
    stack-name: ${{ env.PULUMY_XXXX }}
    work-dir: ${{ env.PULUMY_XXXXX }}
    color: always
    diff: false
  env:
    PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.PULUMI_XXXXXX }}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @jaxxstorm but this has not really made any difference to the output.

Answer (score -1):

You are watching the output of the github action runners right?

Maybe instead of doing that you can configure the pulumi github action with this parameter `comment-on-pr` and you will see the content of the red box in the message of the pr without a need to go to the actions' logs

https://github.com/pulumi/actions#configuration

Because I think is as @Azeem mentioned above. There is no configuration at the moment for that.

Cheers

Comment: I don't fully understand why I got downvoted. This will give exactly that output but as a message on the PR body rather than the logs of the github actions